# How to add a video to the dashboard in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I'd like to add a video tutorial for registered users to my dashboard in wordpress. I tried this code:

```
 `<style type="text/css">
.postbox,
.postbox div.handlediv,
.postbox h3.hndle {
  background: none;
  border: none;                       
}                       
</style>


<?php

/* add content */   
function customContent() {
  echo ' http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rArpyMXT2ew ';
}

/* add widget */
function add_customDashboardWidget() {
  wp_add_dashboard_widget('wp_dashboard_widget', 'Custom Content', 'customContent');
}

/* add action */
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_customDashboardWidget' );

?>`
```

but it only shows the line, not the actual video. What to do?

Comment: [Video tutorials in the Dashboard](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/46445/12615).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like coding, and you want to be able to easily add more videos and adjust which roles can see them, I just released a plugin that does that super easily. It's lightweight and simple at the moment, but it definitely does the trick.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/video-dashboard/